# iPhone - Drawing a target on the UIImagePickerController rejected by Apple

Tags: iphone, app-store

I submitted an application to the AppStore and having it back refused because I was accessing to an undocumented part of the API, which is wrong... I don't do that...

So, I'm using the UIImagePicker to take picture with a target in the middle of the screen,
I added the view with this method [myPicker.view addSubview:myTargetView];

is it allowed? As xCode display this function, I don't feel that I'm accessing to an undocumented method of the SDK...

I'm getting mad with apple and having the application rejected....

Any idea? how can I draw a target over the camera?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for iPhone OS 3.1.  You will be able to do this using public methods in that release.  You can get a start now with the 3.1 beta SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 3.0 documentation states that you should never access the view of the UIImagePickerController directly.

If you read the Device Support documentation in the iPhone Application Programming Guide, there is a section labelled "Taking Pictures with the Camera" where this is mentioned. I'm sure it's stated elsewhere, but this was the first thing I encountered.

Of course, this may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange because we can find lots of application with view drawn over the camera controller...

Comment: I don't think anyone has stated that the functionality you are describing can't be accomplished. However the approach you've taken to accomplish this appears to be an approach that Apple discourages - or at least that's Apple's take on it. This may change (and based on one answer will change) but currently means refactoring your code to get it accepted.